# Extracting url from anchor tag to use in right click menu

Tags: javascript, anchor, event-listener

Hey so I set up a right click menu on my site you can see here

http://www.jaminproud.com

Everything works good except I want to add the abilty to open a link in a new tab. I have looked everywhere and cant find a solid answer for this. I would also need a way to make the menu so that option is only displayed while hovering over an anchor tag. Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S I dont need the actual code written that would be nice but rather just to be pointed in the direction Thanks.

Comment: It is just my two cents but giving a different functionality to right-click annoys users who use it and is useless to users who don't use it (read Mac's). I would just stick with the default behavior (for usability proposes) and let it be.

Comment: Please add to your question the fact that you have mootools framework available for such a task. That would be much easier to find an answer :)

Comment: @Frankie - I use the right-click on my Mac all the time. In general, it is a bit annoying when the default functionality is overridden, but if it is contained to a certain div or portion, it can be very useful.

Comment: @Topher: Yes, but if you look at his site, you'll see that he's replacing the context menu everywhere without adding any real value.

Answer (score 2):

There is now way to specify opening in a new tab yet, but when new browsers support CSS3 we will have the ability to tab link.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new

For now, why not just use target="_new" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the element that was clicked on in the `click` event handler from the `event` object's `target` property.  You can get the tag name using the element's `nodeName` property, and if it's an `A` element, you can get the URL using the `href` property.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are browser specific, so you probably just want to open it in a new window by specifying the `target` attribute in the link like so:

```
<a href='somewhere.html' target='_blank'>My Link</a>
```

Most tabbed browsers will let the user specify if they want it opened in a new tab or a new window when one of these type of links is clicked.